# How to use GetOptions in a Perl module

Tags: perl

I have a main.pl code where I call a perl module function likes this:

```
genspicemeas::genspicemeas({-f=>"filename", -block => $block, -log => $LOG})
#assume block are initialized in the main.pl
```

# LOG is a file handle in main.pl : please specify how to handle this
   # in my GetOptions reference in the perl module

My `genspicemeas.pm` is like below:

```
package genspicemeas;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

sub genspicemeas {
my($opt_file,$opt_block);
GetOptions(
 'f'=>\$opt_file,
 'block' =>\$opt_block);
 print "block name is $opt_block and file name is $optfile\n";
}
1;
```

When I run `main.pl`, I expect it to print the block name and filename 
from the print statement in `genspicemeas.pm`, however those are printing NULL values. It seems the variables are not getting passed to the Perl module I wrote. Please I am new to using Perl modules so please any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, the Heading has a typo...meant in a Perl module and not spice module

Comment: Can someone please assist with my specific question on how to use GetOptions? The answer suggests to use GetOptionsFromArray however i want to use GetOptions. Also please if the response can be specific and not make any assumptions as this is the reason for asking a specific question. Example : instead of GetOptionsFromArray([%{ $_[0] }], ...) , can you please specify the fields.

Comment: This was a good question because it had some specificity.   You need to ask another question. But that said, `GetOptionsFromArray`, per the link in Silvar's comment takes an array as the first argument, and then after a comma takes the hash that you see in all the documentation for `GetOptions` ... So "the fields" are `ARRAY,HASH` ... and there are scads of ways to construct HASH.  Google it.

Answer (score 2):

`GetOptions` processes `@ARGV`, so just add

```
local @ARGV = %{ $_[0] };
```

That said, it's far less magical to use `GetOptionsFromArray` from the same module.

```
GetOptionsFromArray([%{ $_[0] }], ...)
```

---

But there's no point in using

```
genspicemeas::genspicemeas({ -f => "filename", -block => $block })
```

instead of

```
genspicemeas::genspicemeas( -f => "filename", -block => $block )
```

With the latter, you'd add the following instead:

```
local @ARGV = @_;
```

And the following is the `GetOptionsFromArray` approach:

```
GetOptionsFromArray(\@_, ...)
```

---

Note that by using `GetOptions` or `GetOptionsFromArray`, you are subject to options set elsewhere in the program unless you use `Configure` to set them appropriately before calling `GetOptions` or `GetOptionsFromArray`.

---

Finally, I'd simply use

```
sub genspicemeas {
   my %opts = @_;

   defined($opts{f}) or die(...);   # Optional validation.
   $opts{block} //= ...;            # Optional setting default.

   print "block name is $opts{block} and file name is $opts{f}\n";
}

genspicemeas::genspicemeas( f => "filename", block => $block );
```

You can even mix positional and options.

```
sub search {
   my $term = shift;
   my %opts = @_;

   ...
   if ($opts{case_insensitive}) { ... }
   ...
}

search("foo");
search("foo", case_insensitive => 0);
search("foo", case_insensitive => 1);
```

Comment: You can use the `GetOptionsFromArray` function, that allows you to process any array instead of just `@ARGV`. https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Parsing-options-from-an-arbitrary-array

Comment: That should be `GetOptionsFromArray` as in my answer, not `GetOptions`.

Comment: what package should i use in my perl module to use the GetOptionsFromArray function?

Comment: It's from the same module (since 2.36)

Comment: @ikegami, I have  use Getopt::Long; in my perl module and when i run i get this error: Undefined subroutine &genSpiceMeas::GetOptionsFromArray

Comment: It might not be exported automatically. `use Getopt::Long qw( GetOptionsFromArray );` By the way, I believe it's always good to explicitly export what you need. That way, it's easier to find out where a sub originates down the line.

Comment: @ikegami...i dont have that particular function in my package. Reason i wanted help specifically with the GetOptions....can you help correct my line :  GetOptions( [%{ $_[0] }], 'f'=>\$opt_file, 'block' =>\$opt_block);

Comment: I already showed you 5 different ways, 3 of which don't use `GetOptionsFromArray`. That's not one of them

Comment: local  @ARGV = @_; Now when i do the following: GetOptions('f'=>\$opt_file, 'block' =>\$opt_block); print"file name is $opt_file and block is \$opt_block"; It prints out 1 for both values of $opt_file and $opt_block

Comment: Then either the value of `$opt_file` was `1` already, or you used `-f`; and either the value of `$opt_block` was `1` already, or you used `-block`

Comment: I was expecting $opt_file and $opt_block to be the values i passed to the switch options in my main.pl when i called  genspicemeas::genspicemeas(-f=>"filename", -block => $block) in my main program where those are initialized.

Comment: You need `=s`. Comments are not for new questions.